# Setting to get the pretty rational phrases in command window

Tags: matlab

Here I've a rational relation :

```
A =  -(2*omega*(5*omega^4 - 9907*omega^2 + 550))/(omega^6 + 5025*omega^4 + 3344500*omega^2 + 11902500)
```

Is there any setting in Matlab that shows computed results in command window 'like (A)' pretty as below form (both for numeric and parametric results):

```
          -(2*omega*(5*omega^4 - 9907*omega^2 + 550))
A = --------------------------------------------------------
      (omega^6 + 5025*omega^4 + 3344500*omega^2 + 11902500)
```

Comment: [`pretty`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out `pretty`.

From the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html):

> `pretty(X)` prints symbolic output of X in a format that resembles typeset mathematics.

As an example:

```
        /   2       \
sqrt(3) | ---- + #2 | 1i
        \ 9 #2      /
------------------------
           2
```

I don't have the symbolic toolbox, so I can't illustrate with your example.